# Is it possible to back up a partition on an SSD onto an HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, backup

Is it possible to back up a partition on an SSD onto an HDD, in such a way that if something goes wrong with the SSD partition (say it's completely scrambled by some program) you can restore it from backup? I'm only concerned with software errors because I'm repartitioning my Mac and I don't want things to go wrong.

I use a Macbook Air with a Flash drive.

Comment: Yes. As to what specific software to use, that'd be off-topic here. But yes, you can back up to an HDD. Or any number of other media.

Comment: I guess this could be useful :) title says it all http://www.macworld.com/article/2855735/the-paranoid-persons-guide-to-a-complete-mac-backup.html